# Is there any way to retract my suggested edit?

Tags: support, feature-request, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises, suggested-edits

I often suggest tag edits in which I add the [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) tag to homework like questions. In some cases, these questions are closed as *off topic* even before my edit is reviewed. So, in that case, I think it is better to not bother the reviewers with my edit. Because if my edit gets approved, then it bumps the useless closed question to the front page. But there's no harm if it gets rejected. So shouldn't there be an option/feature to retract your suggested edit, like the one we have for flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to retract a suggested edit, as per [this Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/230312) (where it was also suggested that users interested in such a feature should make a [feature-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Mother Meta, but I doubt anyone has in the 8 years since that answer was made).

I don't think that adding [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) to a closed question is a big deal. Sure it'll push it to the reopen queue, but that queue doesn't fill up quite like the close queue does, so having an extra question to address shouldn't be a bad impact.

Comment: I saw the Mother Meta post, and the OP has added the *feature-request* tag. But the answers only seem to provide alternative ways and consolations. What is stopping SE from introducing the new feature which will allow users to cancel their suggested edits?

Comment: @FakeMod not being an SE developer, no idea why they won't do it.

Comment: So what should I do? Making a new post on the Mother Meta will simply result in the closure of that question as a duplicate of the one you mentioned.

Comment: You could see if one of the SE devs answered or commented on that question, or any of the linked ones, and ask them via comments about feasibility of implementing it.

Comment: How do I identify a SE developer? (might sound dumb, but I haven't encountered one yet)

Comment: They have the SE logo (rectangular striped text box thing) next to their names. Shog9 is one and he recently posted a question on our meta, something like "A year in review"

Comment: Oh! But to see that I would have to go to their profiles and check it out. I think it's better to ping @Shog9 so he sees this. I request Shog9 to guide me to how to request this feature. Thanks Kyle :)

Comment: It should be just like the diamond indicating a mod appears next to a users name, you shouldn't have to click on profiles. Additionally, pinging random people doesn't work, they have to have commented first.

Comment: I asked TimPost about this (via a comment) on the Mother Meta post. Waiting for his reply.